# Saved child records is not loading with parent

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

We are using spring data with jpa implementation. When I submit the form I can save  parent and corresponding child records. After save page will get redirect to summary page. Here in the summary page I can read the current parent record but child record is getting empty, hence failing to display the record in summary page but when i restart the server it displays the records.

Can anyone suggest on this.

We are using spring managed transactions

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)

Item item = itemRepository.getOne(itemId);
```

Comment: i can read the same record from dev server but not from local server after save . if once i restarted the local server i can read the record

Comment: Please can you post the source code for the Item entity you are saving, and the full source code for the method doing the saving ?

Comment: Thansks for your response @paulNUk . it seems there was an issue with cache . child is not loading it . i have refreshed the entity in entitymanager and it start working